# Writing C (and variations) on a Mac, and Exporting to Mac AND Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, macos, ide

So I was just told that it's not the easiest thing to write an Objective C program on a mac using xcode that can also be run in windows (because xcode utilizes mac-exclusive libraries).
I'm not too picky about the language I use because I'm just learning, so is there an easy way to program C/C#/C++/Objective C on a mac that can be (easily) exported and run in Windows?

Comment: It depends whether you want to write apps with a GUI or just console apps that use stdin/stdout ?

Comment: @PaulR I'm choosing a language (from a variation of C) and an IDE for mac that will let me publish to windows too (easily). I'm not sure the direction I want to take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compile Objective-C code for Windows on a Mac using [MXE](http://mxe.cc). But I assume you're interested in GUI applications, not just pure, standard Objective-C code. In that case, you will need a cross-platform framework. For example [Qt](http://qt-project.org) (MXE comes with Qt). But that's a C++ framework.

Objective-C for GUI applications is pretty much only used by Apple. If you want better portability of your applications, you should probably use C or C++. Python is another language you can use, if dynamic/scripted languages are your thing. Python also supports Qt, so you can write GUI apps with it.

The reason I recommend Qt over all other frameworks is that it doesn't just give you a GUI library, but it also gives you other classes that make it much easier to write cross-platform applications (for example an easy to use, Unicode string class, and classes for portable file I/O, networking, threading, etc.)

Comment: ok awesome. I'll look into using the Qt library thanks a bunch. (i'm assuming it'll work with xcode? if not can you recommend another IDE & compiler to use?)

Comment: @frescaaaaa Qt supports XCode. But IMO the Qt Creator IDE is much easier to use and is geared towards working with Qt. (You can find Qt Creator on http://qt-project.org/downloads).

Answer (score 2):

Look into cross-platform GUI libraries.  Objective-C is largely associated with Apple products, so I doubt you'll find much cross-platform there.

For C#, the Mono project may be a good place to start:
http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

For C++, you can start by looking at Qt and Wx.

Depending on how much effort it is, you can also try separating out your GUI and trying to use  some GUI scripting languages like Tk.  This has the advantage that you'd have more leeway in your main language.